# Astropy: "ValueError: One of the inputs to search_around_sky is a scalar" in search_around_sky

Tags: python, astronomy, astropy, fits

I would like some good explanation or an example about how Astropy **search_around_*** works. Unfortunately, the tutorial from the official page doesn't help me.

I have a catalogue with ground truth (GT) sources. I also have some  patches (fits images) which include some of the ones that are included in my GT catalogue. I want to find out **which of the sources in my GT catalogue are included in the fits image patch**.

My GT catalogue is organized almost like that:
ID ... RA, Dec... and it is a .txt file

So I want to return which coords in the GT are included in the patch.

What I have done is, I got the WCS from the header of the patch and I have the World center of the image. Then I tried for testing the actual code provided by the official documentation (http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/matchsep.html).

I used the following code, supposing that the 2nd argument of `search_around_sky`  is the degrees that it searches around(??)

```
x,y,w=patch_celestial_center(patch=None) #x,y are the World center of the patch
c=SkyCoord(ra=x*u.deg,dec=y*u.deg,  frame=FK5)

cat=ascii.read("$training_set.txt")

catalogue_coo=SkyCoord(cat["RA(core)"]*u.deg, cat["DEC(core)"]*u.deg, frame=FK5)

idx_1, idx_2 d2d_, d3d_ = catalogue_coo.search_around_sky(c, 1*u.deg)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "$$/train_utils.py", line 49, in <module>
    x,y,w=patch_celestial_center(patch=None)
  File "$$train_utils.py", line 43, in patch_celestial_center
    idxc, idxcatalog, d2d, d3d = catalog.search_around_sky(c, 1 * u.deg)
  File "$$/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astropy/coordinates/sky_coordinate.py", line 1170, in search_around_sky
    storekdtree='_kdtree_sky')
  File "$$/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astropy/coordinates/matching.py", line 330, in search_around_sky
    raise ValueError('One of the inputs to search_around_sky is a scalar. '
ValueError: One of the inputs to search_around_sky is a scalar. search_around_sky is intended for use with array coordinates, not scalars.  Instead, use ``coord1.separation(coord2) < seplimit`` to find the coordinates near a scalar coordinate.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

is it something that  have to do with my data before testing? Is it because of the formation of my catalogue?

Is it something I don't get about the `search_around_sky` functionality?

Please some help!

Answer (score 1):

It's a "scalar" in this sense because it's just a single coordinate (which mathematically we might not think of as a scalar, but since `SkyCoord` can hold an array of coordinates it is the scalar of `SkyCoord`).  I do think it's a bit odd that the `search_around_sky` function can't accept a scalar coordinate because it could in principle detect this case (in fact it already does, and raises the specific exception you get) but instead of raising an exception it could try to "promote" your argument to a single-coordinate array. But I also partly understand the reasoning.

According to [these docs](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/matchsep.html#searching-around-coordinates) the idea is that you should be able to call `catalog.search_around_sky(some_coords, ...)` and obtain a pair of arrays of indices into both `some_coords` and into `catalog` where the matching coordinates are in each of the respective coordinate arrays.  Further more, each of those arrays of indices should be the same size and shape, since the matches must have been found in each of the coordinate arrays.

So if you input "coordinates" is just a single coordinate and not an array, the logic of this function doesn't make any sense.  This is stated in the docs as well:

> Note, though, that this dual-indexing means that `search_around_*` does not work well if one of the coordinates is a scalar, because the returned index would not make sense for a scalar:

```
>>> scalarc = SkyCoord(1*u.deg, 2*u.deg)  
>>> idxscalarc, idxcatalog, d2d, d3d = catalog.search_around_sky(scalarc, 1*u.deg)  
# THIS DOESN'T ACTUALLY WORK  
>>> scalarc[idxscalarc]  
IndexError: 0-d arrays can't be indexed
```

> As a result (and because the `search_around_*` algorithm is inefficient in the scalar case, anyway), the best approach for this scenario is to instead use the `separation*` methods:

```
 >>> d2d = scalarc.separation(catalog)  
 >>> catalogmsk = d2d < 1*u.deg  
 >>> d3d = scalarc.separation_3d(catalog)  
 >>> catalog3dmsk = d3d < 1*u.kpc
```

In this example, `d2d` is an array of 2-D distances between `scalarc` and the coordinates in `catalog`.  Then `catalogmsk` is a boolean mask of those elements in `catalog` where the distance was less than 1 degree.  You can then use this mask to retrieve those elements specifically from `catalog` like `catalog[catalogmsk]`.   Or you can skip assigning the mask to an intermediate variable entirely and just do `catalog[d2d < 1*u.deg]`, for example.

If you look at [the implementation of search_around_sky](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/_modules/astropy/coordinates/matching.html#search_around_sky) you can see that it uses `SkyCoord.separation` internally, but is still quite a bit more complicated because it needs to use search techniques to efficiently find matching pairs of coordinates.

If you just have a single coordinate you want to find matches to within some distance of coordinates in a catalog it's much simpler and more straightforward to use the `SkyCoord.separation` method directly as explained above.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I will use that. In fact, I want to get all the true sources from full catalogue which are included in a small fits image. Search_around_worked properly with the addiion of the [ ], though. However, when I chose as seplimit the distance(in arcmins) between the center of the image and one of the corners, it was returning more sources outside my sky patch

Comment: actually `SkyCoord.seperation` returns exactly the same with `search_around_sky` with the addition of [ ]. And also returns the same sources outside my fits image, If I could guess, by using  wcs info

Comment: Yes, it's to be expected that it would return the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with `c=SkyCoord(ra=x*u.deg,dec=y*u.deg,  frame=FK5)`. Which was considered (don't know why) scalar.

`search_around_sky` accepts *array coordinates*.

So it works fine when instead of `c=SkyCoord(ra=x*u.deg,dec=y*u.deg,  frame=FK5)`
I used: `c=SkyCoord(ra=[x]*u.deg,dec=[y]*u.deg,  frame=FK5)`